# Why does $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}fdm=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\{x:f \geq \frac{1}{n}\}}fdm$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

I just finished proving the following statement from my textbook on measure and integration theory:

$ex$: Let $f$ be a nonnegative measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n}fdm = \int_{\mathbb{R}}fdm$$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Here is my work:

Let $f_{n} = f\chi_{[-n,n]}$, where $\chi_{[-n,n]}$ is the indicator function on $[-n,n]$. Then  $f_n$ is nonnegative , monotone and $f_n\to f$ pointwise. Therefore by the monotone convergence theorem $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n}fdm= \displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}dm=\int_{\mathbb{R}}fdm._{\Box}$$

While I believe this i correct, after completing this problem the author suggests that I should be able to see that $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n}fdm=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}fdm=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\{x:f \geq \frac{1}{n}\}}fdm.$$ For some reason I cannot see why this is true and how I should be able to see it after completing the previous problem? If any one can point this out or provide feedback, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: apply monotone convergence again

Comment: You may want to use $\int_{\mathbb R}f = \int_{f>0}f.$

Comment: @peek-a-boo - hmmm, I'm not sure I understand. How does using the monotone convergence theorem again yield $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}fdm$?

Comment: Let $E_n=\{x:\, f(x)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$. Then, $E_1\subset E_2\subset E_3\dots$ and their union is $\{f>0\}$. So $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f\,dm=\int_{\{f>0\}}f\,dm = \int_{\bigcup E_n}f\,dm=\dots$

Comment: @peek-a-boo - Completing your statement: so by the monotone convergence theorem: $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f\,dm=\int_{\{f>0\}}f\,dm = \int_{\bigcup E_n}f\,dm= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\{x:f \geq \frac{1}{n}\}}fdm = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}fdm$?

Comment: Why do you have the last $=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\,dm$ again? It's like you're proving something is equal to itself

Comment: @peek-a-boo - Thats just what the textbook has, is that not correct or should I just stop at $\int_{\bigcup E_n}f\,dm= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\{x:f \geq \frac{1}{n}\}}fdm$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Sorry for the basic questions, I have just been stuck on this for awhile and wanted to make sure I understand.

Comment: it's correct, but unnecessary. Look at the first thing, $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f\,dm$ and the last thing $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\,dm$ These are the same things apart from notation. The real statement being made is that $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f\,dm=\lim\int_{\{f\geq \frac{1}{n}\}}f\,dm$, hence your first three equal signs are what's necessary. THe fourth is unnecessary.

Comment: @peek-a-boo - Gotcha, and was I correct in thinking that $\int_{\bigcup E_n}f\,dm= \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\{x:f \geq \frac{1}{n}\}}fdm$?

Comment: yes, that's because of monotone convergence.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Wonderful. Thank you for all your help today, it means alot.